# Dotnet Core API Authorization Using Incoming OAuth Bearer Token and JWT

Tags: api, .net-core, oauth, jwt

I need help. I am just trying to implement authorization like below for securing my .NET Core API, here is the details what I am trying to do in .NET Core API.

**Client/Consumer**

When client consuming my api he send bearer token in authorization header and this token is provided by my org OAuth URL. This is the code:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient()
var creds = $"client_id={client_id}&client_secret{client_secret}&grant_type=client_credentials";
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
var content = new StringContent(creds, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var response = httpClient.PostAsync("https://myorg/oauth/oauth2/cached/token", content).Result;
var OAuthBearerToken = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

**Provider/Server/Me**

I need to read this incoming bearer token sent by Client/Consumer

Then, I need to send a request to another api with client income bearer token and this api is provided by my company its called proxy. code like below.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient()
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", IncomingOAuthBearerToken);
var response = httpClient.PostAsync("https://myorg/apis/v1", content).Result;
var KongJWT = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Then, this request provide me a JWT token in response

After that, I need to validate this jwt toke in dotnet core api

In the end, if everything is okay then I need authorized this request and send response data to client/consumer

I am trying to implement this scenario like this in .NET Core API.

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(KongJWT)), //How can set my JWT here because JWT is recived in side OnMessageReceived
                };
                x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    {
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                     {
                        StringValues IncomingOAuthBearerToken  = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
                        var httpClient = new HttpClient()
                        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", IncomingOAuthBearerToken);
                        var response = httpClient.PostAsync("https://myorg/apis/v1", content).Result;
                        var KongJWT = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                        Id(KongJWT IS VALID) THEN RETURN return Task.CompletedTask; ELSE context.faile("invalid token");
                     }
                };
            });
```

Comment: Related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67204985/what-is-konghq-api-and-how-to-protect-my-asp-dot-net-core-api-with-this

Comment: Why the kong flag ?

Comment: Hi @Orel - Because my company is using kong for protecting apis and i am using the same. related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67204985/what-is-konghq-api-and-how-to-protect-my-asp-dot-net-core-api-with-this

Comment: Your question is pure .Net core, nothing on Kong side, using JWT is quite standard, the fact that is Kong as API GW as no impact here IMHO